# Consuming old purchases Android IAB V3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have a problem with testing my app. I have 2 items which user can buy. Some days ago I didn't know that I should consume the purchases. Today I receive code 7 (Item Already Owned) every time when I try to buy one of items because I didn't consume it. What can I do to consume old purchase?

ADDED:
Both items are 'not managed' at Developer's Console

Comment: use consume method to consume the product helperObject.consumeAsync(con, mConsumeFinishedListener);

Comment: I tried, but received code 5 (developer error). But when I'm consuming second item I receiving code 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to consume with wrong token. This code helped me.

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, context.getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0)
{
    ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
    ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
    //ArrayList<String> signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
    //String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");
    for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
        try {
            String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
            final String token = jo.getString("purchaseToken");
            String sku = null;
            if (ownedSkus != null)
                sku = ownedSkus.get(i);
            consume(sku, token, purchaseData);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: what is mService here?

Comment: @PulahNandha It is IInAppBillingService. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) if you need

Answer (score 2):

For consuming inapp product you need get purchase of that sku.
For that you firstly need  or get INVENTORY of all products or do PURCHASE that exact product.

Please check code below which can help you to consume products which were pruchased before.

```
public void consume(final String skuName) {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (inventory.getSkuDetails(skuName) != null){
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(skuName), null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to previous answers, I have this solt. for clearing all purchases

```
import com.android.vending.billing.util.Inventory;
import com.android.vending.billing.util.Purchase;

public class BasePurchaseActivity {

    protected IabHelper billingHelper;
    ...

    /**
     * Means it will clear our the purchase history
     */
    protected void consumeAllPurchases() {

        // You know your product ids
        Set<String> allProductIds = com.demo.myapp.AppMgr.getAllAppProductIds();

        try {

            Inventory inventory  = getInventory();

            for (String curProdId : allProductIds) {

                Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(curProdId);               

                if (purchase != null) {

                    billingHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, null);
                }

            }

        } 
        catch (IabException iabEx) {

            iabEx.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```